# New orders are missing from admin when "Asynchronous indexing" is enabled

Tags: orders, indexing, magento-2.1.7, crontab

After enabling `Asynchronous indexing` new orders are missing from admin and `Order Emails` too not sending.

My `cronjobs` seems to be working just fine & I also tried to run the `cron:run & setup:cron:run` from the CLI but it didn't solve the issue

Any idea what might be the problem?

I know that I should expect delays when using the `Asynchronous` stuff but what's considered to be a normal delay?

Comment: I have found recently that unless you reindex orders do not always display in the admin panel im assuming this would possibly be the same for the emails

Comment: I also tried reindexing manually & it was still missing. How long does it usually take?

Comment: usually it is instant go into your DB and look under sales_order and see if they appear here if not look under quote to see if they have actually been moved if not you may have an issue with your checkout between the payment and completion stage

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cron is configured in your server using this command below.

```
crontab -e
```

Then you can manually run the reindex, then check the cron logs.

```
bin/magento cron:run
bin/magento index:reindex
cat var/log/cron.log
```